# Low-Latency Block Production

Tags: eosio-code

It is possible to spawn your network by forking EOS source code and running the appropriate contracts.

By extension, it is possible to set specific blockchain configuration in such scenario. For example, one could change number of block producers and/or change block time. My question is specific to the latter of these configs. What is the lowest theoretical and practical block time that could be achieved should one spawn a private blockchain?

Network and IO that takes place are probably the biggest overheads imo and the limit would probably be ~100 ms for block time. Perhaps this estimate is biased...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answer to your own question - theoretical maximum depends on the properties as network bandwidth, CPU power and IO. Physical resources on each instance define how fast a private network can process transactions. You need to define these constraints first before one can start to calculate theoretical maximum.  But at least 13k tx per second is a good guess:

https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/90181h/max_eos_transaction_per_second_number/